# Compiling Very Slow On Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compiling

I have an server on which I compile Android ROMs and Recoveries. I had Ubuntu 14.04 on it before. Compiling a recovery took like 4 min. from scratch.

But now, as I've upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, as I type `mka recoveryimage -j24` it just keeps on going on for over 30 min. (Then I canceled it).

My server has very powerful specs and I also have the necessary build tools installed.

I'm currently running Lubuntu Desktop.

Please help me solve this issue.

```
I'm trying to compile TWRP 3.0.2 on CyanogenMod 12.1 source.
```

Comment: Is disk nearly full after upgrading, or after splitting a new partition for 16.04? Is base memory usage at cold boot reasonable or more compared to before?

Comment: @NoBugs No, the disk looks good. And I don't know about base memory usage.

Comment: What is the output of `free` command?

Comment: @NoBugs I'm running Lubuntu Desktop now and this is what it says: http://pastebin.com/8zsgkqyg

Comment: @TanujSingh could you try the commands from this answer  https://askubuntu.com/a/483795/26246 but not sure I they work well with threads & forks.

Comment: Could we get more hardware details. What is your CPU make and model? What CPU frequency scaling driver are you using? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`

Comment: I am noticing the same slow down with my laptop. With 14.04 was perfectly fine. Now it get stuck at some points, with CPU at low percentage usage. Memory is also free.